# how can i convert matching values from columns into a dictionary using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, sklearn-pandas

I have a pandas Data Frame like below :

| v_id | r_id | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 222 | 1 | 1000 |
| 222 | 2 | 1500 |
| 222 | 9 | 600 |
| 33 | 1 | 7000 |
| 555 | 1 | 6000 |
| 555 | 5 | 60 |
| 555 | 7 | 2300 |

how can I convert it to into the following new table :

| v_id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 222 | { 2 : 1500 , 1 : 1000 , 9 : 600 } |
| 33 | { 1 : 7000 } |
| 555 | { 1 : 6000 , 7 : 2300 , 5 : 60 } |

Please note that the values of the dictionary are in descending order.

The dataset has 5000 values, I haven't figured out a solution yet. Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the index and use groupby

```
df.set_index('r_id').groupby('v_id')['count'].agg(dict)

v_id
33                      {1: 7000}
222    {1: 1000, 2: 1500, 9: 600}
555     {1: 6000, 5: 60, 7: 2300}
Name: count, dtype: object
```